# cannot seem to rename the labels in scale_y/x_discrete ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to rename the labels on the the y axis but cannot seem to get it working.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = -x, y = y, color = color),
             size = 4) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_discrete(
    #breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    labels = c(
      "1" = "2009",
      "2" = "2010",
      "3" = "2011",
      "4" = "2012",
      "5" = "2013",
      "6" = "2014",
      "7" = "2015",
      "8" = "1016"
    )
  )
```

I would like along the y-axis the years but the `scale_y_discrete()` doesn't seem to find the correct labels.

When I run:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = -x, y = y, color = color),
             size = 4)
```

I get y-axis labels from 1 - 8. I would like to change them to years.

Data:

```
DF <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L), y = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 
6, 7, 6, 7, 7), color = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("black", "blue", "red", "grey"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-43L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change y to a factor or character, the discrete scale will work.

E.g:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = -x, y = as.factor(y), color = color),
             size = 4) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_discrete(
    #breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    labels = c(
      "1" = "2009",
      "2" = "2010",
      "3" = "2011",
      "4" = "2012",
      "5" = "2013",
      "6" = "2014",
      "7" = "2015",
      "8" = "1016"
    )
  )
```